# Passing data between two view controllers - Clicking a button and passing an image

Tags: xcode-storyboard

I have an application with a few view controllers ( using storyboards).
I'm trying to pass the background image of the button at view controller number 1 to an image view on view controller number 2.

I'm using the push sague to transfer to the second view.

I'v read many articles of how to pass the data using the appdelagate or
the prepareforsauge but no one is working for me.

I would appriciate if someone could explain how to do that with prepareforsague !?

Thank you very much

Comment: Furthermore, the second view controller is a general controller that will receive data from different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using modal option of the storyboard rather than push. It will push the new controller and you don't have to hard code it.